# Некорректная запись данных в файл с помощью writeInt

Tags: java, java-output-stream

Помогите пожалуйста, использую `writeInt` для записи длины массива в текстовый документ, но в блокноте число не отображается (символ пустого квадрата)

```
public static void outputPupils(Pupil v, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(out);
    stream.writeInt(v.getSecn().length());
    stream.close();
}
```

мэйн:

```
 OutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Sfroe\\Desktop\\output.txt");
 Pupils.outputPupils(sb, fout);
```

getSecn возвращает фамилию студента.

Comment: Столько вопросов. Почему в тексте `writeInt`, а в коде `writeByte`? Что возвращает `v.getSecn.length()`? Что Вы ожидали увидеть в файле?

Comment: извиняюсь, в коде должно быть writeInt, по заданию мне нужно записывать в файл длину фамилии перед ее непосредственной записью(это и возвращает v.getSecn.length())

Comment: OutputStream предназначен для записи байт в бинарном режиме. Записанные в таком режиме файлы нельзя читать как текст, что вы пытаетесь делать открывая его в текстовом редакторе.

Comment: Я по ошибке думал, что writeInt предназначен для записи числа. Вот формулировка задания - записать информацию об ученике в байтовый поток (использовать DataOutputStream)
public static void output Pupil (Pupil v, OutputStream out),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DataOutputStream.writeInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt(int)) записывает в поток байтовое представление числа. Например, если в метод передать 10, то будут записаны четыре байта: три нулевых, а последний `00001010`.

Для того чтобы число можно было прочитать в текстовом редакторе нужно, чтобы в файле были записаны символы. Например, для 10 должны быть закодированы символы «1» и «0». Сделать это можно через [`writeBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBytes(java.lang.String)), преобразовав число в строку:

```
 stream.writeBytes(v.getSecn().length()+"");
```

Comment: а вы можете объяснить, в каких случаях используют writeInt?

Comment: @sfroe Данные, записанные с помощью `writeInt` нельзя прочитать как текст, но можно считать через [`DataInputStream.readInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt()). Не всегда важно читать файл самому, можно записывать/передавать данные в двоичном формате.

Answer (score 1):

В параметре `false` - файл будет перезаписываться

```
public static void outputPupils(Pupil v, String path) throws IOException {
     FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(path, false);
     writer.write(v.getSecn().length());        
     writer.flush();
}
```

мэйн:

```
 String path = "ваш путь";
 Pupils.outputPupils(sb, path);
```